# how to sum of alias field in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a query below

```
SELECT  s.reference_no as rno , a.id, a.product_name, a.sale_id, s.id as sale,
        count(CASE WHEN b.id = 1 THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) as tax1,
        count(CASE WHEN b.id = 2 THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) tax2,
        count(CASE WHEN b.id = 3 THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) tax3,
        count(CASE WHEN b.id = 4 THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) tax4,
        count(CASE WHEN b.id = 5 THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) tax5,

       sum(CASE WHEN b.id = 1 THEN a.val_tax ELSE NULL END) sum1,
       sum(CASE WHEN b.id = 2 THEN a.val_tax ELSE NULL END) sum2,
       sum(CASE WHEN b.id = 3 THEN a.val_tax ELSE NULL END) sum3,
       sum(CASE WHEN b.id = 4 THEN a.val_tax ELSE NULL END) sum4,
       sum(CASE WHEN b.id = 5 THEN a.val_tax ELSE NULL END) sum5

FROM    sale_items a
        INNER JOIN tax_rates b
            ON a.tax_rate_id = b.id
         JOIN sales s ON s.id = a.sale_id   
GROUP   BY s.id
order BY sale desc
```

i want an extra coloumn grandtotal_tax (sum1+sum2+sum3+sum4+sum5) . But when i try it throw an error Unknown column 'total_tax_sum1' in 'field list' . So how to sumup the alias field. You can find my three table database schema [here](http://pastebin.com/n32yxdKr)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an alias in the `select` where it is defined.  SImply do:

```
sum(case when b.id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) then a.val_tax end) as grandtotal_tax
```

Note that the `else NULL` is redundant, because `NULL` is the value if there is no match in the `case` statement.

Also, if `b.id` can only take on those five values, this can be simplified to:

```
sum(a.val_tax) as grandtotal_tax
```